# How to call onclick event, reenable function | PURE JS only

Tags: javascript, html, z-index, absolute

I have following function for items inside wrapper.

```
    //vars

    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) (function(i) {
    divs[i].onclick = function showTheA() {
      if (divs[i].offsetHeight == 130) {
        divs[i].style.height = '250px';
        element1[i].style.display = "flex"; // example
        element2[i].style.width = "80%"; //example

      }
      else { 
        divs[i].style.height = "";
        element1[i].style.display = ""; // example
        element2[i].style.width = ""; //example
      }
    };
})(i);
```

Then I overlay the whole item with another element (abcd for example) so it overlays whole content of item, BUT I want to disable onclick event for elements below this overlay.
Element abcd (overlay) has position absolute and higher z-index, but its still possible to do onclick events for `divs` below (change height);

```
divs[i].onclick=null;
```

How do I call the function mentioned above to do the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pointer-events instead.

To disable try:

```
divs[i].style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

To re-enable:

```
divs[i].style.pointerEvents = "";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant click links inside the overlay too.